# Html : to display hexagon progressbar with hoverable sides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I would like to display hexagon progress bar like below in my page.

[image]

where each side represents some data A. On hovering on each side, I would like to display a tool tip saying 'A is done'. How can I achieve this?

I tried SVG  and  and [hexagonprogressbar.js](https://www.jqueryscript.net/loading/Canvas-Based-Hexagon-Progress-Bar-Plugin-with-jQuery-Hexagon-Progress.html). I could create hexagon but I am unable to figure out how to add onhover effect to each side. Any help would be appreciated.

This is how I created hexagon using svg `<path>`

```
<path id="id67441526994471690" d="M150 0 L285 75 L285 225 L150 300 L15 225 L15 75 L150 0" stroke="rgb(49, 120, 115)" stroke-width="35" fill="transparent" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="2160" mask="url(#id67441526994471690)"></path>
```

If I add `onhover` to above it adds onhover even on all sides. I want add seperate event onhover event to each side.

Hexagonprogressbar.js creates same kind of svg.

Comment: please show us what you tried so we can help determine the problem

Comment: I am not familiar with that library, but can't you just add an event handler for mouse over for the side?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: I edited my question. I am adding information about how I used <path> to create hexagon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I drew a hexagon using 6 lines which made it possible to make the sides of the hexagon independent. 
When you hover to each side of the hexagon tooltip appears.

The tooltip is provided by the command svg `<title>`

```css
polyline:hover {
stroke:orange;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    width="350" height="350" viewBox="0 0 80 80"  >  
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#233340" /> 
 
 <g  transform="translate(7 7) rotate(90 32 32)" stroke="#317873" stroke-width="5" stroke-linecap="round">
 <title>A is done </title>
 <polyline id="p1" points="16 4.29, 48.5 4.29" />
 <polyline id="p2" points="48 4.29, 64 32" />
 <polyline id="p3" points="64 32, 48 59.71" />
 <polyline id="p4" points="48 59.71, 16 59.71" />
 <polyline id="p5" points="16 59.71, 0 32" />
 <polyline id="p6" points="0 32, 16 4.29" /> 
 </g>
 
 <text x="25" y="35" font-size="12" fill="#fff" font-family="sans-serif"> Linux</text>
 <text x="27" y="50" font-size="10" fill="#fff" font-family="sans-serif"> 100%</text>
 
  </svg>
```

To see the tooltip, hold the cursor for a while on the side of the hexagon.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the answer. This is more like what I was looking for.